# Connecting vBulletin login/logout with Website

Tags: php, session, authentication, vbulletin

I have a website and it has a vBulletin forum. I need to make a single log in / log out for the entire website. I've already managed to check if the username/password matches but now I need to set things up so it has a unique log in.

Thanks in advance, Simon.

Comment: maybe you can check this :
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/enangyusuf/2010/01/28/vbulletin-bridge-for-cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how vBulletins login system works, but I have done with with phpBB.

Essentially, you need to look through the login files and see how they store login information (for instance, in a session, in a cookie, etc), as well as what information they store (may be a user name and hashed password, or a user id, etc). Then, you need to replicate that functionality in your own code by taking in information, comparing it to the vBulletin database (with the proper hashing), and then pull the needed information and store it in a cookie/session, or whatever is compatibility.

I know that phpBB implemented a login class that one could simple `include` to gain that functionality. You may look into that for vBulletin as well. Sorry I can't be more specific, but hopefully it'll give you an idea of what to look for.